# "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)." while attempting to create a nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am new to creating `nuget` packages and encounter the following issue:

I have a class library project, which I am trying to convert into a `nuget` package.

When I attempt -

> nuget pack MyPackageName.csproj the command fails with "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."

I am using `VS2015`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the command fails with "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."

This error is usually caused by **misconfigured system files**.

In order to exclude the possibility of code errors, you can create a new blank c# library project, build it, then pack the project with the command line `nuget pack MyPackageName.csproj`.

If you can pack it successfully, you should check your scripts in previous project, make sure there is no build error in the it.

If you **could not pack the blank project either**, there is a 95% chance that your computer has registry problems. These Windows errors are easy to repair. By downloading and running the registry repair tool RegCure Pro, you can quickly and effectively fix this problem and prevent others from occuring. After fixing the registry, a quick scan with Spyhunter anti-malware tool will ensure that your PC has no more problems. You can follow below steps to repair the registry:

- [Download & Install RegCure Pro](http://www.freecomputererrorsrepair.com/downloadregcure.php) for Free to Scan Your PC
  Choose the "Repair All" Button after the system has finished scanning.
- [Download & Install Spyhunter Malware Removal Tool](https://www.enigmasoftware.com/products/spyhunter/) - 
  Spyhunter will optimize your PC by removing all traces of Adware, Spyware and Malware. Your PC will run much smoother after this process is completed.
  Choose "Start New Scan" after installing
- Click the "Repair All" Button and follow directions on screen.

Comment: Did the initial suggestion of creating a blank project and it worked! Thank you